# what's the best vim color scheme for presentation on a projector with low display quality

Tags: vim, colors

We need to do code review from time to time in meeting rooms where the owner needs to show his changes (by vim on a **terminal** mostly) on the screen via projector (with very low resolution like 1024x768), the problem is, there's no good color-scheme for vim to make the code changes look pretty.

The issue is, we lose the good part like syntax highlighting with various file type plugins because most of them are based on dark background colours. For dark themes, many decorations on syntax elements just become invisible.

Anyone can suggest a good scheme to fit well in this situation?

Comment: @RudolfMühlbauer We use vim for most of the time on a putty terminal without X display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color scheme. It is probably not the best for use on a projector, but you would have to try that. I found it via the [spf13 distribution](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim).

example: 
[image: Solarized dark in gnome-terminal]

Comment: I find solarized to be way too low contrast unless the font is giant.  It's got some good ideas but you have to choose between eyestrain and not being able to see much content.  Add to that, a putty console is what, 16 color?

Comment: solarized would be just about my last pick for projector. It's intentionally lower contrast to reduce eye-strain.

Answer (score 2):

For a projector, it's most important that the *font* is readable, i.e. it should not be too thin. The default font on Windows GVIM (Fixedsys) does the job quite well. You may want to temporarily increase the font size for better readability (`:set guifont=...`; there are even plugins that allow quick dynamic font scaling via key mappings).

Also, dark letters on a white background usually is best. Any high-contrast colorscheme should work (even the default one, though it certainly isn't pretty). In the end, I think, it comes down to the quality of the projector and the room setup (shades drawn, good projection area).